# Find out the other members of a Google Apps group without admin access

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-groups

My company uses Google Apps and has a number of email lists (I think they're called groups) e.g. group1@example.com.

group1@example.com has me as a member.

Is there any way for me to find out who else in my company is a member of that group without admin access?

Comment: Does anyone know why this isn't available in gmail when it is in google calendar (see answer below)? Does anyone know of any feature requests for it in the gmail product forum which mention it and if it will be added or reasons why not? I searched but couldn't find any. I feel this is one of the main features that I miss in gmail coming from MS Outlook.

Answer (score 11):

Workaround: if you have calendar access, add the group to a calendar meeting, and expand the chevron to see the list. (May depend on Apps administrator granting access.)

**EDIT:** direct access may also work for you according to the following pattern:

```
https://groups.google.com/a/DOMAIN/forum/#!members/GROUPNAME
```

where `DOMAIN` and `GROUPNAME` are replaced by the post- and pre-@ parts of the address, respectively. So in your example case, try

```
https://groups.google.com/a/example.com/forum/#!members/group1
```

Comment: This answers the question of how to view the members. I just discovered this myself too but was hoping there was a way to do it in gmail as well.

Comment: According to a suggested edit, the calendar workaround may not work anymore.  I have no way to verify this.

Comment: @jonsca I have no way to address the suggestion, but it continues to work in my case, as of 12 seconds ago.

Comment: @downwitch All right, no modifications necessary on the answer.  Thanks for verifying.

Answer (score 6):

The Google Apps administrator decides and sets who can see the group members:

[image]

So unless they've allowed you to see them, you can't. :)

Comment: This answer is informative but not directly pertinent: you did *not* answer the question as posed: _How does the user see the membership list of a group?_

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Google Apps script: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/google-groups-and-google-apps-script.html.

The only problem is that it will work only for groups that you are member of.