# Find a member's group memberships in Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-groups

This question is the inverse of [another question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35344/find-out-the-other-members-of-a-google-apps-group-without-admin-access?newreg=bbf1bac1d16549a4ae8061513aeb4b02).  In corporate gmail, I know how to view a list of members for a particular group, but how do I perform the reverse of this?  That is, how do I find out which groups John Doe belongs to?

Use case - I need to send an email with a database question.  I know that John Doe is a Database Administrator, but I'd rather email the group of DBAs instead of just John.  In Outlook, this could be accomplished by double-clicking on John's name; then his email groups would be listed under Memberships (or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

I've never found a good solution to this. Instead, I've used a work around. I have a script that gives me a full list of all of the groups I can access and lists of their members. When I run "main" it creates a Google sheet called "Group List". Although it's not refined, it gets the job done.

```
function main() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.create("Group List");
  GroupsApp.getGroups()
  var groups = GroupsApp.getGroups();
  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    var group = groups[i];
    var gemail = group.getEmail();
    if (group.getEmail().indexOf("my-email-domain") > 0) {
        Logger.log(group.getEmail());
        listGroupMembers(doc, group)
    }
  }

}

function listGroupMembers(doc, group) {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = group.getEmail();
  try {
    var users = group.getUsers();

     var s = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length +
     " members: ";
     for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
       var user = users[i];
       var user_email = user.getEmail();
       s = s + user_email + ", ";
       doc.appendRow([GROUP_EMAIL, user_email]);
     }
     Logger.log(s);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked in Gmail, [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com), Google Plus and Groups and couldn't find this information.  As a Google Apps Admin, however, I can lookup the user and see their groups from their User Account Page.

[image]

If someone else has a better answer I would love to know as well.